# .NET 6 Web API and Redis

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, redis

У меня есть приложение ASP.NET Core WEb API(.NET 6) с сгенерированным кодом в Visual Studiо. Туда я пытаюсь подключить Redis для кеширования. Но когда я патюсь сделать запрос к Redis, то возникает ошибка. Ниже будут примеры кода для работы с Redis:

Program.cs

```
var configurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
{
     EndPoints = { "redis://default:redispw@localhost:49153" },
     Ssl = true,
     AbortOnConnectFail = false,
 };

var multiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configurationOptions);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(multiplexer);
```

WeatherForecastController.cs

```
private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
        private readonly IConnectionMultiplexer _cache;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, IConnectionMultiplexer cache)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _cache = cache;
        }
    
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> Get()
        {
            string recordKey = "WeatherForecast_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmm");
            var db = _cache.GetDatabase();
            string jsonData = db.StringGet(recordKey);

            List<WeatherForecast> weatherForecastArray = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<WeatherForecast>>(jsonData);

            if (weatherForecastArray is null)
            {
                weatherForecastArray = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                    TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                    Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
                }).ToList();

                jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecastArray);
                db.StringSet(recordKey, jsonData);
            }

            return weatherForecastArray;
        }
```

Скриншот с информацией о контейнере из
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Информация об ошибке:

Timeout performing GET (5000ms), inst: 0, qu: 1, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: SpinningDown, last-in: 0, cur-in: 0, serverEndpoint: redis://default:redispw@localhost:49153:6380, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: LAPTOP-JI57EMI1(SE.Redis-v2.6.80.25426), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=8,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=11,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=218), v: 2.6.80.25426 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из описания ошибки. Дело в конфигурации сервера, на котором стоит ваш Redis. Пропускной способности недостаточно. Нужно проверить сколько на сервере ОЗУ, так как редис это хранилище в памяти и ему нужно выделять хорошее кол-во ОЗУ. Также нужен более менее хороший CPU на сервере, на котором живет редис.

Comment: Есть ли какой-то способ это сделать через докер, так как сервер запускается в контейнере. Запускаю на своем ноуте i5 10 поколения и 8 ОЗУ